# Callback to animate jquery ui dropped element

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, draggable, jquery-ui-draggable

I'm trying to animate a div after it has been dragged and dropped with jQuery UI.  I'm using the 'stop' event as per the jQuery UI docs ().

However, I'm really struggling to get the object that has been dropped to be able to animate it.  Here's where I'm at currently, although I've tried several things which just don't seem to work:

```
        $('.item').draggable({
            stop: function (event, ui) {
                $(ui.draggable).animate({ bottom: 0 }, { duration: 1000, easing: 'easeOutBounce' });
            }
        });
```

This is using jQuery 1.9.0 and jQuery UI 1.10.0.

I'm sure this must be simple - I just can't get it to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `ui.draggable` (which is nothing) to `this` and it will affect the dragged div.  Note that the animation may not occur depending on your layout, but I can get it to work with this:

http://jsfiddle.net/T4UDp/

Since the draggable itself changes `top`, `bottom: 0` alone doesn't work.

Comment: Thanks.  `this` was the first thing I tried actually, but I think your other comment is the reason it wasn't working.  i.e. When jquery ui drags something it uses `top` so I can no longer animate `bottom` successfully.  Trouble is, I need the bounce animation to be 'downward' so I need to bounce the bottom rather than the top.

Answer (score 1):

Two issues, here's the fixed code:

```
 $('.item').draggable({
            stop: function (event, ui) {
                $(this).animate({ "top": "0px" }, { duration: 1000, easing: 'easeOutBounce' });
            }
        });
```

First - ui.draggable wasn't actually selecting anything, and was returning undefined. Changed to `this` to affect the dragged elements.

In addition, jQuery wasn't reading the CSS property `bottom`. You'll have to somehow use `top` to achieve your desired effect. In the same way, `left` will work, but `right` will not.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/klatzkaj/kjtD8/